# How to tell Rubocop to ignore a specific directory or file

Tags: ruby, rubocop

My project is extending open-source classes from a third-party gem that we don't want to hold to the same coding standards as our own code.  Refactoring the gem code isn't a viable option.  We just want Rubocop to ignore the copied code.

How can I instruct Rubocop to completely ignore a file or directory?

Comment: Try https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#includingexcluding-files

Comment: Why did you copy the gem's source code into your project's folder?

Comment: spickermann, because we need to modify some methods on the class, and our tech lead said we aren't allowed to use monkey patches to do it.

Comment: As an aside, why is Rubocop picking up the Gem's source code? Did you bundle-install the gem into a sub directory within your project?

Comment: As another aside, if the gem is on github, you can clone the gem's github repo and then point your Gemfile to your clone.  This is very easy to do.

Comment: A new module was written in our code, with classes that extend the CukeForker gem's classes and override their methods, in order to modify the gem's output and colorization.  We had previously been monkey patching the gem's methods, but wanted to do this instead.  However, within one of the gem classes that our module extended and called, an original method was being called instead of our new method, so that code needed to be copied into the new module and modified to call the new class.  It was that code that caused Rubocop to fail.

Comment: The manual section referenced in @orde's comment is now at http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#includingexcluding-files rather than on the github main page.

Comment: @emery why don't you use refinements? http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/

Answer (score 151, accepted):

As per orde's comment with the link to [the manual](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#includingexcluding-files) I found .rubocop.yml and added the following:

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'path/to/excluded/file.rb'
```

where the path is relative to .rubocop.yml

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer, since it's short. One important note I just ran into though: this will override the default AllCops.Excludes, which in Rails mode at least, will prevent rubocop from checking `node_modules` and `vendor`.  So you'll likely want to add those to your excludes as well.

Comment: Note that you can do this for **specific** cops as well. E.g. `Metrics/BlockLength: \n
  Exclude: \n
    - 'Rakefile' \n
    - '**/*.rake' \n
    - 'factories/**/*.rb' \n
    - 'spec/**/*.rb'`  I wish you could do newlines in code snippets for sub-comments.

Comment: Make sure you keep the default values as well (see https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/blob/924b939202eddeee2516aec958a2487356f3e53c/config/default.yml#L63-L67)

Answer (score 62):

From [`rubocop/default.yml`](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml#L60-L62):

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'node_modules/**/*'
    - 'vendor/**/*'
```

Answer (score 39):

Can also consider comments for a single file. Great for ignoring the linter for a quick and dirty temporary task.

```
# rubocop:disable all

module TempTask
  ...
end

# rubocop:enable all
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this won't skip the file, it will only suppress the warning, but Rubocop seems to still check the file.

Answer (score 23):

For your convenience, here is the .rubocop.yml I frequently used.

See formal explanation of .rubocop.yml [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml).

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - Berksfile
    - recipes/basic.rb
    - attributes/*.rb

# Customize rules
Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 95

MethodLength:
  Max: 35

Metrics/AbcSize:
   Enabled: false

BlockLength:
  Max: 70
```

I constantly bump by rubocop errors and warning. Thus I've published this post.

[Common Rubocop Errors: Improve Your Ruby Code Quality](http://www.dennyzhang.com/rubocop_errors/)

Comment: according to the explanation link, it's `Exclude:` not `Excludes:`

Comment: my config needs quotes around the directory or filename

Comment: NOTE: To ignore all subdirectories and files in a directory, use something like this `- tmp/**/*`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a newer version and every time I add `Exclude` rubocop will hang. Turned out I need to tell how to merge `Exclude`. This might work for you

```
require:
  - rubocop-rails
inherit_mode:
  merge:
    - Exclude
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'node_modules/**/*'
    - 'vendor/**/*'
  NewCops: disable
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Rubocop through Visual Studio I could not get the former answers to work.

I eventually noticed that Rubocop was not in fact executing from the root of my project file but from my own root directory and so using:

```yaml
# Doesn't work :(
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - db/schema.rb
```

was failing because `db` was not in the same directory that Rubocop was looking for it.

I then changed it to

```yaml
# Works :)
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - */schema.rb
```

and it works fine. Note there are no quotation marks around the file name.

Comment: The correct config is ` - /**/*/schema.rb`, otherwise it will give you an error

Comment: Actually `/**/schema.rb` is enough. No need for `/**/*/`.