# how to turn off Cyclomatic complexity for where is too high

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have a where method in model that's throwing lint error. The whole code in model is just a test code at this moment and will be refactored later on. So i want to turn off this lint error for now.

**UPDATE**:
Here's the method i am getting lint error at

```
def self.where(start_date, end_date, customer_id, type, location, is_registered)
  filtered_data = if start_date && end_date
                     customers.select do |e|
                       e[:startDateTime].to_datetime >= start_date.to_datetime &&
                         e[:endDateTime].to_datetime <= end_date.to_datetime
                     end
                   elsif start_date
                     customers.select {|e| e[:startDateTime].to_datetime >= start_date.to_datetime }
                   elsif end_date
                     customers.select {|e| e[:endDateTime].to_datetime <= end_date.to_datetime }
                   else
                     customers
                   end

  if !is_registered.nil? # is_registered is true or false
    filtered_data = customers.select { |e| e[:isRegistered].to_s == is_registered }
  end
  # Check if hash presents and check if the keys have valid values.
  if customer_id || type || location
    hash = { customerId: customer_id.to_i, type: type, location: location }
    # delete if type, location or customer_id is nil.
    hash = hash.delete_if { |_k, v| v.nil? || v == 0 }
    keys = hash.keys
    filtered_data = filtered_data.select { |h| h.select { |k| keys.include?(k) } == hash }
  else
    filtered_data
  end

  filtered_data.map do |slot|
    mock_customer(slot[:id], slot[:customerId], slot[:name], slot[:startDateTime],
               slot[:endDateTime], slot[:location], slot[:status])
  end
end
```

I tried adding `# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize` in model but didnt help.

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting? can you show the code or at least the line?

Comment: @TamerShlash Sure please check the updated question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/CyclomaticComplexity
.... your method here
# rubocop:enable Metrics/CyclomaticComplexity
```

Also, if you want to turn off Rubocop for all those test files (since you are going to refactor them), you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896588/368167).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
# rubocop:disable Style/CyclomaticComplexity
yor code
# rubocop:enable Style/CyclomaticComplexity
```